# Ifs, else ifs and multiple returns

Tags: c#, if-statement, coding-style

This is not a question about chained *ifs* or *ifs* and *else ifs*. I've seen quite a few of those questions posted in *SO* already.

My question is also *not about performance*, its more about *coding standards* and *readability*.

Consider the following trivial pseudocode I'm seeing a lot in a project I'm working in:

```
if (expression > 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else if (expression < 0)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

I usually write this kind of construct in a slightly different way:

```
if (expression > 0)
{
    return 1;
}

if (expression < 0)
{
    return -1;
}

return 0;
```

And of course there is the third option that goes by the rule that no method should have more than one return statement which I find too restrictive and cumbersome when the complexity of the method is low:

```
int retVal;

if (expression > 0)
{
    retVal = 1;
}
else if (expression < 0)
{
    retVal = -1;
}
else
{
    retVal = 0;
}

return retVal;
```

Is one of options listed above more correct when writing these type of constructs? Performance wise I know the choice is completely irrelevant but from a readability point of view I kind of prefer avoiding the *if - else if* statements. That said, many co-workers don't agree with me even though they can't give me any convincing arguments.

Comment: It's a preference thing.

Comment: It's all about what you prefer. I'd say the first option looks best, as it groups the related if's together in a logical manner. And if you (can) skip the braces it'll look a lot neater.

Comment: Down voters care to comment?

Comment: @InBetween: sure. The problem with your question is that there is no good or bad answer. Stackoverflow is not appropriate to debate of such things.

Comment: this would probably be better asked on programmers.stackexchange

Comment: I have a preference for option 3. Since more than 10 years, we avoid using "break" (except in switch statements) and "return" (except at end of function). The experience showed that this coding standard provided some readibility benefits and, in debug mode, there is some advantage in setting a single breakpoint at the end of a procedure.

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon Then vote to have it locked. Downvotes, IMO should be for downright inaproppriate questions of  the type: "do my homework for me",  "C# is broken, my code does not work (followed by 1000 lines of code)" or "I want to write a 3D engine in C#, please give me sample code"...

Comment: @Graffito, if you are still using 10 year-old coding standards you might want to review them, eg if you use dictionaries of lambdas or pattern matching, then if/else if and switches can be deprecated and avoided; likewise using linq largely removes the need for loops, so break becomes a non-issue. Finally, if you keep all methods to eg < 25 lines, readability is easy, regardless of the number of returns.

Comment: @ David Arno: we are still maintaining and upgrading programms older than 10 years. when looking at c# code posted to this forum, you will see a great number of "if" statements (and some "switch") in the code. Do you have any reference to a coding standard where "if" statements are banned?

Comment: @Graffito, who said anything about banning `if`'s? That would be silly. By adopting better coding practices though (eg read up on clean code, solid, functional techniques etc), then you become less reliant on cyclomaticly complex approaches such as `switch` and chained/nested `if/else if`'s.

Comment: @David Arno: my initial comment adresses the use of "return" within conditional instructions, e.g "if" (nested or not).

Comment: Upvote from my side. Although is a thing of preference, it's interesting to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
return expression < 0? -1:
       expression > 0? +1:
       0;
```

In general, it depends very much on preferences and semantics.

If all three cases (`>0`, `<0`, `==0`) are somewhat symmetric, then your first option looks good for me.

If the default path should return `0`, and  cases `>0`, `<0` are special/exceptional, I would go for the second option.

Comment: The example was over simplified. When the return statements are a bit more complex  I think using the `?` operator can get in the way of readability, specially when chained.

Answer (score 1):

There are many approaches. You could take one of the two approaches you show. You could do:

```
if (expression == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
return expression < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

Or fully use the ternary operator:

```
return expression == 0
    ? 0
    : expression < 0 ? -1 : 1;
```

Yet another option is to use a functional approach, such as [offered by my own SuccincT library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SuccincT/1.2.0) and do:

```
return expression.Match().To<int>()
                 .Where(e => e < 0).Do(-1)
                 .Where(e => e > 0).Do(1)
                 .Else(0).Result();
```

It's all a matter of preference and there really isn't a right answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think for

```
int retVal = 0;

if (expression > 0)
{
    retVal = 1;
}

if (expression < 0)
{
    retVal = -1;
}

return retVal;
```

This does not look performance wise correct and reason being every time it is doing condition matching.

Rather in following case this will match till it finds correct condition and ignore rest

```
if (expression > 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else if (expression < 0)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

I think if/else if / else is better over performance
For readability perspective you can also prefer using
case
I think performance wise if else if is better choice than multiple ifs

Comment: I'm sorry but performance wise both options are the same; both implementations will evaluate the same number of conditions before reaching any given return statement.

Comment: @InBetween Not true. In the first example, if `expression > 0` is true it will still evaluate `expression < 0` since there's no return.

Comment: Whoops sorry! I thought you were comparing the first two options. I had already edited my answer because evidently the unique return option makes no sense without *else if* so I misread your answer. Sorry about the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

> As Mentioned in the question
>   " My question is also not about performance, its more about coding
>   standards and readability."

you can use ternary operator for simple if and then else case, but if you are checking multiple conditions using ternary operator it will not remain readable.

```
return expression > 0 ? -1 : 0;
```

For conditions having multiple checks use if and else-if as you have provided in your question.

```
if (expression > 0)
{
    return 1;
}
else if (expression < 0)
{
    return -1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
```

This answer has been updated after getting remarks from @Chris and @InBetween

Comment: I'd say having any nested ternaries is completely unreadable. There is absolutely no advantage in doing that.

Comment: I'm sorry to say, but IMHO more than 2 nested ternary operators is hell. I tend to avoid even 2 and refactor them in code reviews whenever I can.

Comment: @InBetween. as i mentioned in the answer that is a suggestion when you use more than 4-5 nested ternary operator, it will be impossible to manage and understand. So according to me going to 4-5 nested ternaries may be understandable but going beyond must be avoided

Comment: I'd sure like to see code with 5 nested ternaries. I cannot imagine it'd be readable.

Comment: @Chris and InBetween Thank you for your precious suggestions. i have updated the answer.